# @Mock objects returning null

Tags: junit, nullpointerexception, mocking, mockito, junit4

So I have code below-

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TeamSubscriptionServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private TeamSubscriptionService teamSubscriptionService;

    @Mock
    private ImsCustomerProfileService imsService;

    @Mock
    private IUserService userService;

    @Mock
    private HttpRequestService httpRequestService;

    @Mock
    private ISubscriptionDbService subscriptionDbService;

    private String imsToken = "IMS_Token";

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        when(imsService.getAccessToken()).thenReturn(imsToken);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(teamSubscriptionService, "jilEndpoint", "www.testJil.com");
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(teamSubscriptionService, "adobeIOApiKey", "api_key");
    }


    @Test(groups = { TestGroup.UNIT_TESTS })
    public void testAddSeat() throws IOException {

        String teamId = "TestTeamID";
        String locale = "En_US";
        String jasonValue = "TestJasonData";
        String apiCallContent = "addSeatAPIResult";

        HttpResponse addSeatResponse  = mock(HttpResponse.class);
        when(addSeatResponse.getCode()).thenReturn(200);
        when(addSeatResponse.getContent()).thenReturn(apiCallContent);

        HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
        when(httpRequestService.makeHttpRequest(anyString(),anyString(),anyMap(),anyString())).thenReturn(addSeatResponse);

        String result = teamSubscriptionService.addSeat(teamId,locale,jasonValue,response);
        assertNotNull(result);
        assertEquals(result, "addSeatAPIResult");
    }
}
```

When I test it I get a NullPointerException on the line

```
when(httpRequestService.makeHttpRequest(anyString(),anyString(),anyMap(),anyString())).thenReturn(addSeatResponse);
```

I feel that all the objects annotated with @Mock are somehow null and the object are not getting injected to the teamSubscriptionService object.

Any Idea whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing TestNG and JUnit annotations.

Test method is annotated with `@Test(groups = { TestGroup.UNIT_TESTS })` - it is clearly a TestNG annotation [@org.testng.annotations.Test](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/Test.html), because JUnit's equivalent does not have element called `groups`.

However, you are using JUnit's `@Before` annotation on `setup()` method, therefore this method is never invoked. TestNG equivalent for this annotation is [@org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/BeforeTest.html). Use it instead.

```
<...>
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
<...>

public class TeamSubscriptionServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private TeamSubscriptionService teamSubscriptionService;
    @Mock
    private ImsCustomerProfileService imsService;
    @Mock
    private IUserService userService;
    @Mock
    private HttpRequestService httpRequestService;
    @Mock
    private ISubscriptionDbService subscriptionDbService;

    private String imsToken = "IMS_Token";

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        <...>
    }

    @Test(groups = { TestGroup.UNIT_TESTS })
    public void testAddSeat() throws IOException {
        <...>
    }
}
```

As a side note, `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` is redundant as well, when using TestNG.

Comment: @Tapan I will appreciate a lot, if you accept my answer, since it works for you.

Comment: Done...I am new here...Had to figure out how to accept an answer ;)